# DeclareMathOperator in bold

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Ho can I declare a math operator which will appear in bold font?

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{Div}
\newcommand{\Divxk}{\mathbf{\Div}_{X/k}}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\mathbf` around `\Div` does nothing, because `\Div` is translated internally to something like "choose the `\mathrm` font and typeset ‘Div’”. Math fonts don't inherit features from the context: `\mathrm` always corresponds to the upright text font in medium weight (or boldface) if `\boldmath` is in force.

You can check that

```
$\mathbf{\mathrm{x}}$
```

produces a medium weight ‘x’.

So you have to define

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{\mathbf{Div}}
\newcommand{\Divxk}{\Div_{X/k}}
```

The definition of `\Div` becomes “choose the `\mathrm` font and typeset ‘`\mathbf{Div}`’”, so, for the same reason as before, the boldface font will be chosen.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{\mathbf{Div}}
```

Comment: That works, so you could define `\DivB` as a bold version of `\Div` for use as required, but that may not necessarily meet the OP's use case.  The general question of why `\mathbf{\SomeMathOperator}` doesn't have the desired effect (and what to do about it) may be more interesting.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach is to use `\boldsymbol`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{Div}
\newcommand{\Divxk}{\mathop{\boldsymbol{\Div}}_{X/k}}

\begin{document}
\( \Div \)

\( \Divxk \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: The spacing is wrong; try `$a\Divxk b$`, where the operator nature is lost. It should be `\mathop{\mathbf{Div}}_{X/k}`.

Comment: @egreg Of course!  Thanks for pointing that out.  Answer updated.